# Java HttpServer: Check that connection is alive with compressed response

Tags: java, connection, compression, httpserver

I need a check that a client is still connected to the server.
Without using compression, such a code works fine

```java
OutputStream os = exchange.getResponseBody();
os.write(someByte);
os.flush();
```

Now I have to apply data compression. So an additional header was added and compressed stream is used

```java
exchange.getResponseHeaders().put(
    "Content-Encoding",
    Collections.singletonList("deflate")
);
DeflaterOutputStream deflater = new DeflaterOutputStream(os);
```

Compression works fine. But "alive checking" does not work anymore. `os.flush()` and `deflater.flush()` do not rise an exception even if the server sends to closed client kilobytes of data.

How to check connection when compression is used?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I added a second argument to `DeflaterOutputStream` constructor to synchronize streams:

```java
DeflaterOutputStream deflater = new DeflaterOutputStream(os, true);
```